# Linq to sql - delete some related records

Tags: linq-to-sql, foreign-keys

I´m using linq to sql and I have a lot of tables with foreign keys leading to the UserId.

Is it possible to have some of these foreign tables cleaned upon deletion.

For example I want the users profile (other table) to be deleted automatically with the user but not the users forum posts.

Is this possible or do I have to handle this with code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386925.aspx) is very usefull.

> LINQ to SQL does not support or
>   recognize cascade-delete operations.
>   If you want to delete a row in a table
>   that has constraints against it, you
>   must complete either of the following
>   tasks:
>
> - Set the ON DELETE CASCADE rule in the foreign-key constraint in the
>     database.
> - Use your own code to first delete the child objects that prevent the
>     parent object from being deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Have not yet tried this, I've had my hands full with other stuff. I'll try this today and mark as answered if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with code, but couldn't you set the Cascade on Delete option in SQL?