# Foreign Key constraint issue when deleting from multiple tables using linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have two tables with a foreign key constraint how can I delete rows from both of them in one transaction?  linq to SQL seems to call my deletes in the wrong order.  Is there somewhere I can check and make sure the constraint is recognized properly by linq to SQL??

```
 DataContext.OtherImages.DeleteOnSubmit(myOtherImage);
 DataContext.Images.DeleteOnSubmit(myImage);
 DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

The Foreign key constraint is on OtherImages.  Thanks!

Comment: "SQL seems to call my deletes in the wrong order.

" - you sure about that?. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509842/linq-to-sql-delete-some-related-records

Comment: Right, it is supposed to, but then why the foreign key constraint error?  If it did them in the order I did there should be no issue, right?

Comment: It may not be an answer to your question but you can create the foreign key such that when the row in `Images` table is deleted, it automatically deletes the rows in the table `OtherImages` that forieign key referenced. Check out `ON DELETE CASCADE` from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: @mozillanerd : same advice was given in the SO link I posted....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have something like

```
[Association(
    Name="FK_OtherImages_Images",
    Storage="_OtherImages",
    OtherKey="ImageId",
    DeleteRule="NO ACTION")]
public EntitySet<OtherImage> OtherImages{
    ...
}
```

in your Image class.

```
DataContext.OtherImages.DeleteOnSubmit(myOtherImage);
DataContext.Images.DeleteOnSubmit(myImage);
DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

should work fine.  My guess is that you're forgetting about another foreign key.  You can see what query is being run by doing

```
DataContext.Log = Console.Out;
```

or something equivalent.  I wouldn't recommend cascading the deletes just to make this work since it should work without doing that.

Comment: It was another key to a resizes table that I forgot about.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

simple logic

set the foreign key relationship

go to option :: Table designer

1. Enfore for replication : NO
2. Enfore foreign key constrain : NO